# How to fetch the mobile browser Url which is opened when click on a link on mobile native application using Appium/Android Driver

Tags: java, android-emulator, appium

Steps:
I have opened login page in mobile app
There is a link to Forgot Your Password?
When we click on Forgot Your Password link, it opens up the link in mobile browser
Now, I need to switch to browser and fetch the browser Url.

Can you please advise how this can be done?

Please note that I am trying these steps on Android device.
Mobile App screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z9kk.png)
Mobile browser screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6p2k.png)

Comment: is there anyway we can fetch url of the link in mobile app? But there is no attribute with the link value is displayed when I try to inspect the element

Comment: You did not mention which driver you are using. Is it mobile driver, or a driver for testing a browser on a mobile device? That is, are you configuring the appium driver for testing an application (.apk file) or a url that is launched in the browser?